# How to directly use javascript's color validation?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, browser, colors

Recently i have been looking for ways to check if a value is a valid CSS color (hexa, rgb/a, hsl/a, names). I could use regexes but i didnt find any code that covers all color's format and I am not good enough to make it myself.
Then I realised if you assign a value to the `style.color` property of a DOM element the value of `style.color` is changed only if you gave it a valid color. **I would like to find the code used by javascript/browsers to validate colors, if somebody know where i can find it, I would appreciate it.**

I wrote this function but the job would be done faster by using the "lower-level" check of javascript/browsers.

```
function isColor(supposedColor)
{
    var colorChecker = document.createElement("span");

    colorChecker.style.color = supposedColor;
    if(colorChecker.style.color != "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't even think that your approach is necessary slow. But maybe instead of creating the element each time, just keep it there and then just set the background-color back to "" after each test.

Comment: also, have a look here: http://formvalidation.io/validators/color/

Comment: think about using colors in CSS only

Comment: Your approach seems good enough.. also, why not use `document.documentElement.style.color` instead of creating new element every time